# PHP Front Controller to get the Contents using HTACCESS file

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to get make pretty URL. I have added a front end controller which gets the URL 
and here is the Code for HTACCESS file and controller

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|search\.php|lib|css|ajax|includes|js|classes|parts|pages|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Controller file

```
$URL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$all_parts = explode("/", $URL);
```

My URL is something like

```
www.example.com/pretty-ulr/10.html
```

I get the page id which is `page.php?p_id=10` (This is a simple example. I am using more complex example. )

But I am not sure how to get the contents here or redirect t0 page.php?p_id=10 to get show this page contents. When I redirect using header(), It does not get there

May be something small in .htaccess file, but I am not sure. Any idea please how to get the page contents.

Comment: If you're using a Front Controller, why not *use* it to load the requested page rather than using `.htaccess` to do it all? Just send *everything* that isn't a physical file to `index.php` and let your application do the work.

Comment: The front-end controller is nothing just a simple file with above code to check URL's only. I am not using any MVC. Using .htaccess to send request to controller and then check from there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like this in `.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.php
```

Then in php do:

```
$url=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urls=explode('/',rawurldecode(trim($url["path"],'/')));
new Controller($urls);
```

The class `Controller` would parse the urls and get the right view.

Comment: The front-end controller is nothing just a simple file with above code to check URL's only. I am not using any MVC. Using .htaccess to send request to controller and then check from there what is the URL.